How can an iPhone use mobile data for internet but also connect to an Access Point without Internet?
In this scenario I have an iPhone with a 5G connection.
I have a PC on a local network WIFI that has No Internet whatsoever.
I want to be able to use my iPhone on my 5G connection, while I still maintain connection with my PC that has the wifi with no internet.
Wifi Assist does not help here because when Wifi Assist detects no internet connection, it breaks the wifi connection and periodically tries to swap you back when internet is restored, which will never happen - this wifi connection has no internet.
So, How can an iPhone use mobile data for internet but also connect to an Access Point without Internet?
